# Ember-cli build error-- The Broccoli Plugin: [broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler] failed with:

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

### Build error

```
corporate-dashboard-app/templates/geospatialview.hbs (in 
H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 
4\Corporate 
Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-
app\tmp\broccoli_persistent_filtertemplate_compiler-input_base_path-
K5dlxt4H.tmp)
```

### The Broccoli Plugin: [broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler] failed with:

```
Error: Parse error on line 7:...cation}} </h5>      {{/#each}}      {{outlet}
----------------------^

 Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
at Object.parseError (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:25665:23)
at Object.parse (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:25734:34)
at Object.parse (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:25317:59)
at Object.preprocess (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:23690:77)
at precompile (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:11991:34)
at Object.precompile (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler.js:11155:12)
at Object.template (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\utils.js:29:40)
at TemplateCompiler.processString (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\index.js:68:36)
at Promise.then.result.output (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\lib\strategies\persistent.js:41:23)
at initializePromise (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:588:5)


The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
at TemplateCompiler.Plugin (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
at TemplateCompiler.Filter [as constructor] (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\index.js:62:10)
at new TemplateCompiler (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\index.js:20:10)
at TemplateCompiler (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\index.js:12:12)
at Object.toTree (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars\ember-addon-main.js:32:34)
at H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli-preprocess-registry\preprocessors.js:180:26
at Array.forEach (native)
at processPlugins (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli-preprocess-registry\preprocessors.js:178:11)
at module.exports.preprocessTemplates (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli-preprocess-registry\preprocessors.js:161:10)
at EmberApp._processedTemplatesTree (H:\learning\Udacity\Udacity Senior Web Developer Nanodegree\project 4\Corporate Dashboard Application\p1\corporate_dashboard-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:836:48)
```

i was trying to get a json file displayed in a handlebar template using

```
{{each model}}
```

npm version:4.1.1,
node version:6.9.1,
ember-cli version: 2.10.0,

Comment: It's just compilation error. show us hbs file.

Comment: hbs file    
`{{model}}
 
 
  {{#each model as |item|}}     
    <h5>{{item.company_location}} </h5>
  {{/#each}}
  
{{outlet}}
`

Comment: why is this error occurring,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` syntax is wrong. try the below,

```
{{model}} 
{{#each model as |item|}}   
<h5>{{item.company_location}} </h5> 
{{/each}} 
{{outlet}}
```

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam
didn't noticed # at the end tag